# Face Recognition API on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, cortana-intelligence, face-api

I need to know, what is the latency for faceAPI recognition in general and how much time taken for face recognition from application to Cortana intelligence.

Comment: How did this get an upvote, then? `:--O`

Comment: did you know the answer?